SFTP setup with multiple users
I am setting up SFTP in a Linux machine. Below are few details on existing folder structure:
/var/home/outbound/
/var/home/outbound/user1
/var/home/outbound/user2
/var/home/outbound/user3

I have created a group sftpusers and added the users 1, 2, and 3. Home directory of each user is as below:
For user1: /var/home/outbound/user1
For user2: /var/home/outbound/user2
For user3: /var/home/outbound/user3

I updated SSHD config file with below details:
Match Group sftpusers
    ChrootDirectory /var/home/outbound
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no

Each time any user tries to SFTP, they will be landed onto /var/home/outbound folder (as this is set as ChrootDirectory) and will be able to cd into all the folders under outbound directory. But the requirement I have is that, user1 should be able to SFTP into his specific folder - /var/home/outbound/user1 and user2 should be able to SFTP into his specific folder alone - /var/home/outbound/user2 and so on.
I have also tried below options in the SSHD config file:
Option1:
Match Group sftpusers
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no

Option2:
Match Group sftpusers
    ChrootDirectory /var/home/outound/%u
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no

In both the cases, I got below error:
fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/var/home/outbound/user1" [postauth]
How should my SSHD config file be updated to accommodate this?

Since the error complains about the ownership and permissions of that directory, at the very least you should include those details into he question, no?

Please do not multi-post. For the record, another copy is on Super User.
